# Database migration MS SQL Studio 17 to Microsoft Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have received the below errors while trying to migrate the MS SQL database to Azure SQL database.

1. Error Validating elements [Login_Name]: User:[Login_Name] has an unresolved reference to Login [AMD_Readonly]
2. The element User:[Login_Name] has property AuthenticationType set to a value that is not supported ij Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

Please guide me how to get rid from this issue.

Comment: Azure SQL Databases are contained databases; you'll need to use the security model within the database, you can't use a `USER` mapped to a `LOGIN`.

Comment: could you please help me to understand which tool you are using to migrate? also, are you using bacpac or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

With this given information, I suggest you to use Azure Data Migration Assistant (DMA) to detect compatibility issues that can impact database functionality in your new version of SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

As you have given below error:

> The element User:[Login_Name] has property AuthenticationType set to a
> value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

It seems like this is a feature in your source database which doesn't supported in Azure SQL Database, hence you are getting this error. To detect similar issues and recommendation, you can use DMA.

You can find the other [DMA Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#capabilities) to know more.

[Check for SQL Server Compatibility Issues when Migrating to Azure using DMA](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5454/data-migration-assistant-dma-to-check-for-sql-server-compatibility-issues-when-migrating-to-azure/)